# Usb Autorun and Batch File

Tags: batch-file, autorun

I am trying to set up an autorun.inf file and batch file in order to check to see if a program is installed.  If not, I want to run the install file upon plugging in the usb drive. Here is my code:

```
setlocal
set VMP=C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Player\
cd C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Player\
if exist %VMP% (
start vmx
) else (
start VMware-player-2.5.2-156735.exe 
)
```

vmx is a shortcut in the root of the usb stick that points to the .vmx file I want to run.  It is opening both files at the same time regardless of whether %VMP% exist.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: FYI, i would not expect this to work in windows 7 - they have changed autorun for removable storage devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your paths in quotes.

```
setlocal
set VMP="C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Player\"
cd "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Player\"
if exist %VMP% (
start vmx
) else (
start VMware-player-2.5.2-156735.exe 
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary for neither the set nor the cd commands. Both deal fine with spaces in paths.